# How to Limit Method (3 iterations) by Date Order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, methods

How can we list a User's unaccomplished goals (aka those he hasn't done yet) to the upcoming 3 he has coming up in descending order?

Ex:

```
Run a marathon 3/1/15*
Create an app 4/1/15*
Buy a house 5/15/15*
Win political office 1/1/16
Marry a wife who can cook & code 2/2/16
       *How to show only the first 3?
```

The purpose is to show this code in the sidebar for User reference.

**views, goals, _upcoming.html.erb**

```html
  <table>
    <% @unaccomplished_goals.each do |unaccomplished| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <b><%= link_to edit_goal_path(unaccomplished) do %>
        <%= unaccomplished.name %>
        <% end %></b></td>
        <td>
          <%= unaccomplished.deadline.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
        </td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>
```

**goals controller**

```html
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @goals = Goal.all.order("deadline")
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
    end 
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @goal = current_user.goals.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
    if @goal.save
      redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @goal.update(goal_params)
      redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @goal.destroy
    redirect_to goals_url
  end

  private
    def set_goal
      @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @goal = current_user.goals.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to goals_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @goal.nil?
    end

    def goal_params
      params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :deadline, :accomplished, :tag_list)
    end
end
```

**Thank you =]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# class Goal
scope :top_3, -> do
  order("deadline DESC").
  limit(3)
end

# GoalsController
def index
if params[:tag]
  @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
  @goals = Goal.all.order("deadline")
  @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
  @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
  @top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3
end

# views/goals/_upcoming.html.erb
<table>
  <% @top_3_goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>
          <%= link_to goal.name, edit_goal_path(goal) %>
        </strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= goal.deadline.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I  use `.top_3` just in the sidebar so that all the `@unaccomplished_goals` will still be listed out in the index?

Comment: Save it off to a different variable. I'll update my answer when I get back to a computer.